# Laravel 5.2 chaining methods

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have two tables:

`organisations` contains:

```
id   name   address   subscription_plan_id   .... other columns
--   ----   -------   --------------------
1    xyz    123 St    23
```

`subscription_plans` contains:

```
id   name      cost    .... other columns
--   -------   -----
23   monthly   12.00
```

I have a class for each where I set up the following Eloquent relationships:

Class `Organisation`:

```
public function subscriptionPlan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(SubscriptionPlan::class, 'id', 'subscription_plan_id');
}
```

Class `SubscriptionPlan`:

```
public function subscriptionPlan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubscriptionPlan::class, 'subscription_plan_id', 'id');
}
```

In my controller I want to create a collection with selected columns from each table, using the Eloquent relationships, but I have not managed to do this without essentially using SQL... I extract each collection with the following commands:

```
$subscriptionPlans = SubscriptionPlan::all();

$organisations = Organisation::all();
```

How do I extract one collection chaining the relationships and nominating the columns I want?

Something like the blow (which does not work):

```
$organisationsAndPlans = Organisation::all()
         ->subscriptionPlan()
         ->get('organisations.col1', 'subscription_plans.col3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply eager load the relationship by using the `with` method on the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class.

```
Organisation::with([
    'subscriptionPlan' => function($query) {
        // Here you have to select the key that is being 
        // used by the relationship no matter what.
        return $query->select('id', 'col2'); 
    }
])->get('col1');
```

This will allow you to choose what columns you want to select from the relationship.

Comment: Happy new year guys! Thanks for the replies. I will try and report back (before the end of 2015!)

Answer (score -1):

```
$organisationsAndPlans = Organisation::select('table1.col1','table2.col2')
->with('subscriptionPlan')
->join(function($join){
       $join->on('table2.ref_id','=', 'table1.id'});
->get();
```

Comment: You should either specify the table or use the `select` method on the query builder class of the relationship.

Comment: I misregarded a part of the question but as I edited it is perfectly fine !